# Reference request for finite simple exceptional group of lie type $E_7(q)$ and its Schur covering group $2.E_7(q)$?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, algebraic-groups, schur-multipliers

Does anyone have the paper named *'Génerateurs, relations et revêtements de groupes algébriques'* written by Robert Steinberg in 1962, or any other reference for simple groups of Lie type $E_7(q)$ and its Schur cover $2.E_7(q)$?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The paper appears on page 113 of "Robert Steinberg Collected Papers" published by the AMS. A link to the Google books version is [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=j3cr_NpG69UC&pg=PA133&lpg=PA133&dq=G%C3%A9nerateurs,+relations+et+rev%C3%AAtements+de+groupes+alg%C3%A9briques&source=bl&ots=0v95HB59gl&sig=ACfU3U078N1q9DaepXdAmcI37xcIh6KhQQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2lZ7KoIPpAhX0QhUIHdv8A64Q6AEwBnoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false), with the paper in question appearing there in full text.

Comment: Thank  you very much!